# SWIFT 3 : set target UIViewController name from dynamic string in didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I've a struct that contains a link value of type String .. the String is the name of a ViewController. I want to pass this value to a UICollectionView didSelectItemAt and Hero transition to the corresponding UIViewController .. but I'm stuck on how to use the String value to instantiate the ViewController object.

My collectionView is working fine, struct data's being passed to cells and displaying .. just can't work out how to use the link String with didSelectItemAt ...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print((tableRows[indexPath.row] as! Projects).link) // proves the String is available for use

    let vc = (tableRows[indexPath.row] as! Projects).link as UIViewController
    vc.isHeroEnabled = true
    vc.heroModalAnimationType = .zoom
    self.hero_replaceViewController(with: vc)

}
```

throws:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'UIViewController' in coercion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift uses static typing, not dynamic typing. This is not Objective-C! You cannot turn a string into a view controller type, still less into an actual view controller instance as you seem to be trying to do. Finally, you don't want to say `as UIViewController` in any case, because a plain vanilla UIViewController has no `isHeroEnabled` property. You must instantiate the *actual type of view controller* that you are trying to create, and the name of that view controller cannot be hidden from the compiler and used only at runtime; it must appear right there in your code.

Comment: no dynamic typing! thanks! your response made me think .. use a conditional statement to set the _actual_ view controller.

Comment: good, I was going to suggest that (but wasn't entirely sure that was what you were even trying to do, sorry)